# Riemann-Hurwitz proof from Lang's Introdution to Algebraic and Abelian Functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-forms

I was studying the proof of the Riemann-Hurwitz formula in the book *Introdution to Algebraic and Abelian Functions* by Serge Lang (chapter 1, section 6):

> **Theorem**. Let $k$ be algebraically closed, and let $K$ be a function field with $k$ as constant field. Let $E$ be a finite separable extension of $K$ of degree $n$. Let $g_E$ and $g_K$ be the genera of $E$ and $K$ respectively. For each point $P$ of $K$, and each point $Q$ of $E$ above $P$, assume that the ramification index $e_Q$ is prime to the characteristic of $k$. Then $$2g_E-2=n(2g_K-2)+\sum_Q (e_Q-1).$$
>
> *Proof*. If $\omega$ is any non-zero differential form of $K$, then we know that its degree is $2g_K-2$. Such a form can be written as $ydx$, with $x,y\in K$. We can also view $x,y$ as elements of $E$; we can compute the degree in $E$, and compare it with that in $K$ to the formula, as follows. Let $P$ be a point of $K$, and let $t$ be a local parameter at $P$, that is an element of order $1$ at $P$ in $K$. If $u$ is a local parameter at $Q$, then $$t=u^ev,$$ where $v$ is a unit at $Q$. Furthermore, $dt=u^edv+eu^{e-1}vdu$. Hence $$\operatorname{ord}_Q(ydx)=e_Q\cdot\operatorname{ord}_P(ydx)+(e_Q-1).$$ Summing over all $Q$ over $P$, and then over all $P$ yields the formula.

I have two questions:

- I don't see why $dt=u^e dv+eu^{e-1}vdu$ implies
  $$\operatorname{ord}_Q(ydx)=e_Q\operatorname{ord}_P(ydx)+(e_Q-1)$$
- When we have the following formula
  $$\operatorname{ord}_Q(ydx)=e_Q\operatorname{ord}_P(ydx)+(e_Q-1)$$
  it says that summing over all $Q$ over $P$ we are done. I don't see why, since:
  $$\sum_Q\operatorname{ord}_Q(ydx)=\sum_Q e_Q\operatorname{ord}_P(ydx)+\sum_Q(e_Q-1)$$ Hence, in order to finish the prove we need that $\sum_Q\operatorname{ord}_Q(ydx)=2g_E-2$ and $\sum_Q e_Q\operatorname{ord}_P(ydx)=n(2g_K-2)$, but none of this formulas seems trivial to me.

I am not sure whether these facts are easy consequences of previous results of the book or not, since there are not any similar result in the previous sections. (As a extra, if someone can write the whole proof with all the details I will be very grateful.)

Comment: How is the canonical class defined? For me it is defined exactly as the divisor of any differential form (the divisors of any two differential forms differ by a principal divisor, hence their classes are the same).

Comment: @Whatsup ok... you are right, so my first question was trivial I'll edit the post.

Comment: Is Segre Lang related to Serge Lang at all?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo

Comment: Your exposition is hard to follow for anyone who doesn't have the book in front of them because you've left out many details. What's the relation between $P$ and $Q$? (Does $P$ map to $Q$?) Why are you choosing $ydx$ as your differential form? What are $x$ and $y$ - how were they chosen? What are $E$ and $K$? Your final line has a sum over $Q$ of a quantity depending on $P$ - again, you need to explain how $P$ and $Q$ are related to have this make sense.

Comment: @KReiser I added links to the statement and proof of the theorem, hope it helps to understand the notation.

Comment: For the future, please know that [images of text and mathematical expressions are discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged) - I've formatted the content of these images using MathJax for you this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\ord{\operatorname{ord}}$

**Question 1**: Given a differential form $ydx$, and a point $P$ with uniformizer $t$, we can write $ydx=fdt$ at $P$ for a unique rational function $f$. Then $\ord_P(ydx)=\ord_P(f)$. Let's use this to compute $\ord_Q(dt)$: as $v$ is in the local ring at $Q$, the valuation of $dv$ is non-negative, so $\ord_Q(u^edv)\geq e$, and as $e\neq 0$ in $K$ we have $\ord_Q(eu^{e-1}vdu)=e-1$. As the valuation of the sum of two elements of different valuations is the smaller of the valuations, $\ord_Q(dt)=e-1$.

Now what happens if we consider $sdt$? Since multiplication adds valuations, we see that $\ord_Q(sdt)=\ord_Q(s)+e-1$. But $\ord_Q(s)=e_Q\ord_P(s)$, and as $\ord_P(s)=\ord_P(sdt)$ we find that $\ord_Q(sdt)=e_Q\ord_P(sdt)+e-1$. Writing $ydx$ as $sdt$, we find the equation we're looking for.

**Question 2**: Start with $\sum_Q \ord_Q(ydx)$. This is just the degree of the differential form $ydx$, which is the degree of the canonical class on $E$, or $2g_E-2$. Next, for the sum $\sum_Q e_Q\ord_P(ydx)$, reindex this in to a sum over all $P$ by writing it as $\sum_P \sum_{Q\mapsto P} e_Q\ord_P(ydx)$. Since $\sum_{Q\mapsto P} e_Q=n$, this becomes $n\sum_P\ord_P(ydx)$, which by the same logic as the first part of this question is exactly $n(2g_K-2)$.